# Add JSON item into localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, local-storage

I'm working on an angular task and the goal is to add items to be purchase into localStorage before adding to cart.

I have four different object that users can add, item can be added several time, so the general condition is if object exist on localStorage and user add it other time I should update quantity attribute, if not add new object with new attribute quantity = 1.

here is the service :

```
  addGiftToCard(type) {
    let cardParse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []
    let index = _.findIndex(cardParse, item => item.type && item.id == type.id)
    if (index == -1) {
      type.qte = 1
      cardParse.push(type)
    } else {
      cardParse[index].qte += 1
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cardParse))

  }
```

and the function in my component :

```
 addGiftToCart(type) {
    let index = this.cartService.addGiftToCard({ type: type })
  }
```

html :

```
<div class="available-checks" *ngIf="!(types === null)">
    <div class="row checks-list">
      <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let type of types">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-8 logo-container justify-content-center">
                <img class="card-logo" src="../../../assets/images/logo-gold.svg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 icon-container justify-content-center text-center">
                <img [src]=" serverUrl+'/'+type?.image" alt="" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row desc-title-c">
              <p class="desc-title">Chèque cadeau</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row type-c">
              <p class="check-type">{{type.type}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container">
              <p class="offer">{{type.designation}}</p>
              <p class="price">{{type.amount}}€</p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <button class="btn btn-footer" (click)="addGiftToCart(type)">Ajouter au panier</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem I got here is the one object added what ever the item is and only the quantity attribute counter updated and got json format like that :

[image]

and If I set **type = type.type** in the service function It works and I got json like that

[image]

I need the json element type do not contain an attribute qty, qty should be outside the object attributes like the first image !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have used `item.type.id` instead of `item.id` like below

```
 let index = _.findIndex(cardParse, item => item.type && item.type.id == type.id)
```